# How to create multiple tables from same CTE?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, create-table

According to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162978/using-a-create-table-as-select-how-do-i-s), to create a table using a CTE, the `WITH cte AS` clause needs to fall within the `CREATE TABLE AS` (CTAS) statement.

I have a CTE that I want to use to create multiple tables, and believe it'll be really inefficient to embed it multiple times in each `CTAS` statement.

Is there a way to re-use my CTE to create multiple tables?

Comment: No you can't (as far as I know). But you can create a temporary table from the cte and create all the tables that you want by selecting from that temporary table.

Comment: That should work, thank you!